# Uninstalled original alarm by accident on samsung galaxy ace ii x (gt-s7560m)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, alarm

I rooted my phone and uninstalled the alarm app thinking i could find a better one, which i couldn't. I was wondering if any one knows how to go back and reinstall it? Thanks

Comment: The usual answer: Restore the backup you've made before starting to manipulate your system. As everybody else, I'm sure you've made one (← Lessons to learn ;) Luckily, RainyTaxi found a "backup" on XDA you might install.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already rooted your phone, this should help. 
[Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1558337)!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, in case the link dies, your answer becomes useless.